# How can I use the same font as the h1 tag with font shorthand without having to specify the font size again?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I am trying to use font shorthand in my h1 tag. However, it's not working when I don't specify the font size in the shorthand. I want to use the same font as the h1 tag in my .title class.

This is my current HTML code:

```html
   <div class="landing">
       <h1 class="title">
           Hello there
       </h1>
   </div>
```

And this is my current CSS code:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: var(--font-size-lg);
}
.landing .title {
    font: bold var(--main-font), var(--fall-back-font);
    line-height: calc(var(--line-height)*2);
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

I have tried setting the font shorthand property in my `.title` class to use the same font as the h1 tag, but it doesn't work unless I also specify the font size in the shorthand.

I want to be able to use the same font without having to specify the font size again.

Answer (score 1):

The [specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-fonts/#font-prop) (see also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)) for the `font` property **requires** that you specify the `font-family` **and** the `font-size`. (The other properties it is a shorthand for are optional.) You can’t use it without specifying the font size as to do so would be a syntax error.

If you just want to set the `font-family` then use the `font-family` property instead of the `font` shorthand property.

Answer (score -2):

to achieve, there are 'css selectors' :

```
div, .title{} // div and also .title
div > .title{} // all childs of div with the class .title
div + .title{} // the first div neighbour with class .title
```

just add the selector of your choice with the div css part.

update :

shorthand need a value, you have to initialise the value before recall it

```
html{ // as global container
var(--header-color, blue); // setting the --header-color first with 'blue' value
}
```

then in your css statements :

```
h1{
color: var(--header-color);
}
```

Comment: in my example the h1 and .title its the same tag : `<h1 class="title">`